# Moq - can't mock class - can't implicitly convert type

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moq

I have a public class that implements IQueryResult and produces a DTO.  It has one public `name` field. I created it just to figure out what's going on. It seems simple enough but I keep getting the error below.  Any idea what's going on?

```
ProjectsControllerTests.cs(40, 21): [CS0029] 
Unit\ProjectsControllerTests.cs(40,21): error CS0029: 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Moq.Mock<...Queries.Results.Woot>' 
to '....Queries.Results.Woot'
```

//Class Woot

```
public class Woot : IQueryResult
{
    public Woot(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

// Declared in test class

```
private static Woot _woot;
```

// Mock in SetupClass

```
_woot = new Mock<Woot>();
```

Comment: why are you mocking `Woot`? Show the test and the subject under test in a [mcve]

Comment: Also if you want access to the mocked object call  `_woot = new Mock<Woot>().Object;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error shows that you are trying to assign `Mock<Woot>` to a `Woot` variable.

While this feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), if you want the mocked object you call `Mock<T>.Object` property

```
var mock = new Mock<Woot>();
_woot = mock.Object;
```

Or using `Mock.Of<T>()`

```
_woot = Mock.Of<Woot>();
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use that framework.

Comment: Thanks kindly.  The `.object` was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are creating a Mock off of a concrete implementation instead of an interface. The Mock lends itself to "mocking" the concrete object.

Try `Mock<IQueryResult` instead

Example: [How can I use Mock Objects in my unit tests and still use Code Coverage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336288/3928095)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete a file with tests from the project and make revert with git, IDK why it helps but I also had this problem with VS after moving logic to another interface, maybe something is cached somewhere.